# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I am scared to put my money in a bank in my country because it is in debt and I'm afraid the bank won't be able to preserve it in the future, I want to ask whether it would be safe and what would be my alternatives?

Would that question be on-topic?

Answer (score 5):

No. This could be answered maybe in https://money.stackexchange.com/ 
but I would suspect only in very general terms, and so in not a very helpful manner.
Essentially, this requires consulting services, namely professional services for a fee.